# Способы конвертации JsonArray в ArrayList<MyModel> kotlin android

Tags: android, json, arraylist

Я получаю с сервера данные и в итоге из того что я получил делаю JsonArray. Но мне нужно как-то конвертировать этот JsonArray в обычный массив объектов класса. Есть конечно [способы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305836/convert-jsonarray-to-arraylist), действующие по принципу - взял из одного массива и добавил в другой, приблизительно действующие так:

```
List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
if (outputs!= null) { 
  int len = outputs.length();
  for (int i=0; i<len; i++) { 
    JSONObject o = (JSONObject) outputs.get(i);
    list.add(new MyObj(o.getString('name'), o.getString('URL')));
  } 
}
```

тут конечно используется `JSONObject` а у меня `JsonObject` используется, но разницы особой не будет я думаю. Я сейчас пытаюсь сделать так:

```
val testArray = tpsObject.getAsJsonObject("questions")[tpsSelection[0].toString()].asJsonArray
  for (i in 0 until testArray.size()) {
Log.i("m",Gson().fromJson(testArray.get(i).asJsonObject.toString(),QuestionModel::class.java).question.toString())
   }
```

но получаю ошибку:

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonArray
```

когда я просто пытаюсь вывести массив:

```
Log.i("m",testArray.get(i).asJsonObject.toString())
```

то все нормально выводится в логи, и остается только как-то конвертировать в нужный. Пробовал так:

```
val jsonParser = JsonParser.parseString(testArray.get(i).asJsonObject.toString())
val model: QuestionModel = Gson().fromJson(jsonParser, QuestionModel::class.java)
```

и получаю такую же ошибку как и выше. Какие могут быть варианты выполнения данной задачи?

Comment: Gson может конвертить разные варианты, но как это оформить на котлине не знаю. На java это бы выглядело примерно так: `QuestionModel[] model = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, QuestionModel[].class);` (где `jsonArray` - это ваш массив с типом `JsonArray`)

Comment: QuestionModel[].class а почему тут массив так указан? или это не массив? я просто использую ArrayList и думал что везде так можно делать)

Comment: У вас в вопросе написано: *обычный массив объектов класса*, и так мы передаём класс массива (не массив), чтобы библиотека создала массив нужного типа. Для коллекций с дженериками вместо этого нужно передавать  `TypeToken`, созданный как-то так: `TypeToken<List<QuestionModel>> list = new TypeToken<List<QuestionModel>>() {};` Аналогичный вопрос с примерами на котлине: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853750/kotlin-convert-json-array-to-model-list-using-gson/54043686

Comment: Так не работает? `val gson = Gson()` `val list = jsonArray.map { gson.fromJson(it, QuestionModel::class.java) }`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, так не пробовал,  добавил ответ со своим способом, посмотрите пожалуйста может добавите что-то от себя :)

Comment: я уже добавил, и ваш код можно заменить тем, что я написал. А вы программируете не на котлин, а на java с использованием котлина, и это `tpsJsonArray.asJsonArray.get(i).asJsonObject.toString()` вообще что то страшное

Comment: я вообще на котлин пишу)) пытаюсь во всяком случае)) сейчас попробую то что вы написали :)

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, а что не так в той строке что вы указали? или вы про `.asJsonArray` имели в виду?)

Comment: tpsJsonArray уже jsonArray, т.к. вы сделали .asJsonArray до цикла. Зачем опять это делать, непонятно, да и вообще там можно оставить только tpsJsonArray.get(i). А ещё лучше сделать `for (element in tpsJsonArray)`, а внутри просто `fromJson(element, QuestionModel::class.java)`

Comment: хм...так и правда работает и выглядит более адекватно чем то что у меня было)) спасибо за совет :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему так:

```
val tpsJsonArray = tpsObject.getAsJsonObject("questions")[tpsSelection[0].toString()].asJsonArray

for (i in 0 until tpsJsonArray.size()) {
   val questionModel: QuestionModel = GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(tpsJsonArray.get(i).asJsonObject.toString(), QuestionModel::class.java)
   selectedTPS!!.add(questionModel)
}
```

в итоге получаю массив состоящий из объектов которые можно уже обрабатывать дальше. Может кому пригодится :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58340517/7540461